# Python: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'violinplot'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've been working with matplotlib for the past few weeks, learning how to make different graphs and such. I am currently at a stand still. I am working with gene expression data, so I have a csv file that contains 3 columns of data (mutated, frameshift and nonmutated). However, I am attempting to make a violin plot and I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fmohamed/Documents/violinplot_script.py", line 39, in <module>
    axes.violinplot(all_data,
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'violinplot'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but my code is located below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

#import data:
with open('/home/fmohamed/Documents/oc_data.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    array = []
    for row in spamreader:
           array.append(row)

# sort out bad data:
splitArray = [row[0].split(',') for row in array]
splitArray = [row for row in splitArray if row[0] != '' and row[1] != '' and 
row[2] != '']
descr = splitArray[0]
splitArray.pop(0) #remove the column descriptions from array
all_data = []
for row in splitArray:
    all_data.append(float(row[0]))
    all_data.append(float(row[1]))
    all_data.append(float(row[2]))

all_data = np.array(all_data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 5))

# plot violin plot
axes.violinplot(all_data,
               showmeans=False,
               showmedians=False)
axes.set_title('violin plot')


# adding horizontal grid lines
axes.yaxis.grid(True)
axes.set_xticks([y+1 for y in range(len(all_data))])
axes.set_xlabel('xlabel')
axes.set_ylabel('ylabel')

# add x-tick labels
plt.setp(axes, xticks=[y+1 for y in range(len(all_data))],
     xticklabels=['mutated', 'frameshift', 'nonmutated'])

plt.show()
```

Thank you all in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)

Comment: As the exception message suggests, `axes` is a NumPy array of 3 `Axes` objects. You can do `axes[0].violinplot(first_dataset)` (so you'd need a loop to plot all three datasets). As @chthonicdaemon suggests, look into Seaborn and its `FacetGrid` objects if you want a way to make that violin plot for all three datasets in a single command.

Comment: BTW, your `all_data` array appears to be a single 1d array. Is that what you intended? If so, what's the purpose of your three separate columns in the `subplots` call?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of matplotlib, since violinplots are available only since [matplotlib 1.4](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/users/whats_new.html). To check matplotlib version, just type into your python terminal:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__version__
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue. The problem is that when you add multiple subplots, the `axes` object is no longer of Matplotlib `axis` type, but a Numpy array of several such objects.

The solution is to do the call to `violinplot` in a loop:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.violinplot(all_data,
               showmeans=False,
               showmedians=False)
    ax.set_title('violin plot')
```

Note that if you have both rows and columns >1, you need to have a nested loop since you have a 2D Numpy array.

Of course this just repeats the same plot many times, so you likely want to put several different examples of your `all_data` into a Numpy array with the same dimensions as `axes`